# How to keep bluetooth turned on even when Windows 7 laptop is shutdown + booted up again?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bluetooth

While it's easy to turn on my bluetooth via <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>, I would like for my bluetooth to stay on even after the laptop has been shutdown and then booted up later. How do I set Windows 7 to do this? I'm on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Fn + F3 seems to be a specific shortcut of your notebook, not general in windows. Have you been looking for manufacturer tools? Please edit your post and tell us what you tried already.

Comment: Yeah the bluetooth shortcut is specific, I just included it there to show how I'm activating bluetooth. However, I believe keeping the bluetooth itself on even after restarting seems to be something Windows 7 will handle as opposed to manufacturer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Placing as answer as too long for comment, not sure if this will be the fix however worth checking/trying:

Go to Control Panel by clicking the Start button, and then clicking  Control Panel. In the top right search type  Bluetooth, and then click Change Bluetooth settings. Click the Options tab change the below settings:

Select the check box for Allow Bluetooth devices to find this computer.

Select the check box for Allow Bluetooth devices to connect to this computer.

Also check for any other setting in here that could be helpful to your issue. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Also adding to this if you go to Start > Run > type MSConfig and press OK. This should bring up your system configuration, go to tab Startup and make sure that anything relating to Bluetooth is ticked to start.

Comment: Hi! [This is how](http://i.imgur.com/w6VhwKG.png) I have it set up from the start. I also checked MSConfig already and everything that has bluetooth in the name is already checked.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question years after it was posted. Posting answer for the benefit of anybody else googling for answers.

To my understanding, this feature is likely a part of the laptop firmware, and not the operating system. You might be able to try looking for a setting in the laptop's bios.